# Using slime's C-x C-e (Eval the form under the point) with swank-clojure in emacs

Tags: clojure, swank

I'm using swank-clojure in emacs on OSX.  I'm able to run a slime session.  When I use C-x C-e on a simple form in a .clj file like

(+ 7 7)

I get an sldb buffer with

Unable to resolve symbol: + in this context
  [Thrown class java.lang.Exception]

I'm able to evaluate that form in the slime session directly.  I was hoping the form in the clj file would get evaluated in the running slime session.  Can someone explain how C-x C-e works in swank-clojure and how I can get the form to be evaluated in the running slime session?

Thanks,

hhh

Comment: This sounds like a setup problem to me. Your example works fine in my emacs swank-clojure setup. I suspect there is some issue with the configuration.

Comment: Can you check if C-c C-c works? It should work similar to C-x C-e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crtl-C Crtl-C is the slime "evaluate this" sequence. This is different form the emacs "eval sexq".